# Array to Comma separated string and for last tag use the 'and' instead of comma in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked many questions and answers regarding join array with comma separated string, But my problem is that, I am making the string readable for human i.e I  have tags array that's if their is two tags, then it would be `tag1 and tag2` and if their is 100 tags then it would be `tag1, tag2, ,,,tag99 and tag100` for last one use the `and` and before using the comma as a separator.

Any way to handle in JQuery?

Comment: I have tried join function, but problem with that that function is working just like implode

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `.slice()`:

```
> var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> [a.slice(0, -1).join(', '), a.slice(-1)[0]].join(a.length < 2 ? '' : ' and ');
'1, 2, 3, 4 and 5'
```

- `a.slice(0, -1).join(', ')`: takes all but the last element and joins them together with a comma.
- `a.slice(-1)[0]`: it's the last element.
- `.join(a.length < 2 ? '' : ' and ')`: joins that string and the last element with `and` if there are at least two elements.

Comment: It does not work perfectly, just try with an array of 1 element.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I did write that the code only works for arrays with more than one element.

Comment: @Blender initially I downvoted the answer since I didn't notice the part where it says it does not work for <= 1 elements.

Comment: One of my favorite functions that I've seen in SO so far. Great answer!

Comment: FYI to new readers, this was updated to work even with 1 element.

Comment: The updated answer works perfectly with 3+ items ("foo, bar and baz"), 2 items ("foo and bar"), 1 item ("foo") and even 0 item (empty string "").

Comment: Great one liner solution for 1 or more than 1 array elements everrr!

Answer (score 38):

Another quick solution is to replace the last comma with and.

The following code:

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4];
a.join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and');
```

should do the trick. (Also, play with the regex modifiers to your need).

One probable issue might be of time when you have large array, but it should work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it will work with lists of length 1. Only gotcha is it won't work if the list contains strings containing the comma, but a workaround for that is to use placeholder strings and then substitute those if that's a legitimate concern. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

I use the regex for that.

```js
var words = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

var commaWord = words.join(', ');
Output: "One, Two, Three"

var commaAndWord = commaWord.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ' and$1');
Output: "One, Two and Three"

var singleLine = words.join(', ').replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ' and$1');
Output: "One, Two and Three"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var substr = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
    var commaList = '';

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < substr.length; ++i) {
        if (i == substr.length - 1)
            commaList += " and " + substr[i];
        else
            commaList += ", " + substr[i];
    }

    console.debug(commaList.substr(2, commaList.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

(note: you may skip to the end to find the final ready-to-pick code)

The one-liner from [Blender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251822/array-to-comma-separated-string-and-for-last-tag-use-the-and-instead-of-comma/16251861#16251861) works great, though I'd favor something more understandable:

```
function arrayToText(a) {
    if (a.length === 0) {
        return '';
    } else if (a.length === 1) {
        return String(a[0]); // cast to string, for consistency with the other cases
    } else if (a.length === 2) {
        return a.join(' and ');
    } else {
        return a.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' and ' + a[a.length-1];
    }
}
```

The same using a switch, see how nicer it is to read:

```
function arrayToText(a) {
    switch (a.length) {
        case 0:
            return '';
        case 1:
            return String(a[0]); // cast to string, for consistency with the other cases
        case 2:
            return a.join(' and ');
        default:
            return a.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' and ' + a[a.length-1];
    }
}
```

Of course, these codes can be shortened/optimized, for example by merging the "0", "1" and "2" cases into just the `a.join(' and ')` from the case "2". I let you tweak these codes according to your taste :)

Finally, here is my end result, I think it has a great balance between understandability, shortness and efficiency:

```
function arrayToText(a) {
    if (a.length <= 2) {
        return a.join(' and ');
    } else {
        return a.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' and ' + a[a.length-1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve it using reduce as well:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
items.reduce((acc, curr, i) =>
    i !== 0 ? acc + `${items.length - 1 === i ? ` and  ` : ', '}` + curr : curr, '');
// "1, 2, 3, 4 and  5"
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After writing this answer, I saw [one by @diegodsp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65182267/14550434) that uses the same regex as mine, so I guess I accidentally stole his answer. Oh well!

---

This one works good for me, and you can use an Oxford comma if you like.

```js
const formatArray = (arr, oxfordComma = false) => 
  arr.join(", ").replace(/,([^,]+)$/g, `${oxfordComma ? "," : ""} and$1`);

const testArray = ["abc", "def", "efg", "abc abc", "fjdsakfj asd", "jfjfjf jfjfj"];
console.log(formatArray(testArray));
console.log(formatArray(testArray, true));
```

Explanation of the regex:

`,` - matches a ","
`([^,]+)` - captures any character except for a "," one or more times
`$` - matches the end of a line

The `$1` in the replacer string represents the captured word.

Comment: Is not the same regex. My is a replacement of last group. 

Answer (score 0):

In order to address all scenarios, from empty, single, two elements or up to multiple elements, we can use slice method more efficently in this way:

```
[...array.slice(0,-2), array.slice(-2).join(' and ')].join(', ')
```

Explanation:
It is divided into three parts: 
1.- `...array.slice(0,-2)` will address all escenarios beyond two elements.

2.- `array.slice(-2).join(' and ')` will address the last two elements by joining them with " and ".
3. The previous parts are joined with `.join(', ')` only in case the first part has elements, otherwise no commas will be added to the output.

Usage:
As an inline function: 
`((array) => [...array.slice(0,-2), array.slice(-2).join(' and ')].join(', ') )(["apple", "banana", "orange"])`

Or as a function:

```js
function smartJoin(array) { return [...array.slice(0,-2), array.slice(-2).join(' and ')].join(', ') }

/*Unit tests:*/
var array1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
console.log(smartJoin(array1)); // 'apple, banana and orange'
var array2 = ["car", "bike"];
console.log(smartJoin(array2)); // 'car and bike'
var array3 = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "fish"];
console.log(smartJoin(array3)); // 'dog, cat, bird and fish'
var array4 = ["pen"];
console.log(smartJoin(array4)); // 'pen'
var array5 = [];
console.log(smartJoin(array5)); // ''
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can also do the following:

1. Create comma-separated string.
2. Reverse it.
3. Replace the first occurrence of `' ,'` with `' dna '` (`'` and `'` backwards).
4. Reverse it again.

```js
[1, 2, 3]
  .join(', ')
  .split('').reverse().join('')
  .replace(' ,', ' dna ')
  .split('').reverse().join('')
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly and it's a one liner, not sure why there's so many downvotes... should be the accepted answer. Definitely better than the other answers.