# Making the full sentence bold, even after added 'and' in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the message I'd like to display based on some values.

I have 4 categories that have some values and I need to display the message if they show high risk. The message is based on the number of risks which can be from 1 to 4 factors hence two messages where I'm using "factor IS" and "factors ARE". 
My problem is I cannot make those factors bold after I add 'and' in my else statement. The beginning of the sentence is bold but not the last risk which comes after 'and'.

I'm adding 'and' before the last item of my array as I don't want comma (I found the code on: [Array to Comma separated string and for last tag use the 'and' instead of comma in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251822/array-to-comma-separated-string-and-for-last-tag-use-the-and-instead-of-comma)).

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

function displayMessage() {

```
    var getRiskFactors = calculateRisk();
    var getRiskFactorsLength = getRiskFactors.length;

    for (var i=0; i < getRiskFactorsLength; i++ ) {

        if(getRiskFactorsLength === 1) {

            var message = "Your main risk factor is your <b>" + getRiskFactors[0] + "</b>";

        } else {

            //this joins items from the array with comma if there's 
            //more than one factor.
            //it also adds "AND" before the last item in the array    
            // instead of comma

            var message = "Your main risk factors are your " + [getRiskFactors.slice(0, -1).join(", "), getRiskFactors.slice(-1)[0]].join(getRiskFactors.length < 2 ? "" : " and " + "</b>");
        }

    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: " and " + "</b>" which means you are literally ending the bold tag after "and". Forgot to add parenthesis?

Comment: Hi there, can please create fiddle for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not starting and closing the *bold tag*

```js
let getRiskFactors = [ 1,2,3,4 ];
var output = "Your main risk factors are your " + [ "<b>" + getRiskFactors.slice(0, -1).join(", "), getRiskFactors.slice(-1)[0]].join(getRiskFactors.length < 2 ? "" : "</b> and <b>") + "</b>";

document.body.innerHTML = output; 

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @ren Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced your start `<b>` tag in the `else` clause and you are always adding a closing `</b>` tag after each and.

Just enclose the whole thing like this:

```
else {
    var message = "Your main risk factors are your <b>" + [getRiskFactors.slice(0, -1).join(", "), getRiskFactors.slice(-1)[0]].join(getRiskFactors.length < 2 ? "" : " and ") + "</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a balance between writing concise code and debuggable/readable code. This is a good illustration of trying to be too clever. I tried to make your code a little more readable.

In my experience I have found errors arise when using concatenation of strings and the ?: operator on the same line. Try the following code and edit as necessary.

```
    var getRiskFactors = calculateRisk();
    var getRiskFactorsLength = getRiskFactors.length;

    for (var i=0; i < getRiskFactorsLength; i++ ) {

        if(getRiskFactorsLength === 1) {

            var message = "Your main risk factor is your <b>";
             message+= getRiskFactors[0] + "</b>";

        } else {

            //this joins items from the array with comma if there's 
            //more than one factor.
            //it also adds "AND" before the last item in the array    
            // instead of comma

            var message = "Your main risk factors are your ";
            var arraypart1 = getRiskFactors.slice(0, -1).join(", ");
            var arraypart2 =  getRiskFactors.slice(-1)[0];
            var computation = getRiskFactors.length < 2 ? "" : " and ";
            var joinedarray = [];
            joinedarray.push(arraypart1);
            joinedarray.push(arraypart2);
            message += joinedarray.join(compution)  + "</b>";
        }

    }

    return message;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm a beginner so it might look a bit too clever although I wasn't trying to be. I will try this, thanks!