# Jquery, Printing multiple values with separating comma

Tags: jquery

I have json like this:

```
obj = [{"name":"Jim Smith","role":"Author"},{"name":"Julie Smith","role":"Author"}]
```

I would like to print the name of the authors like this:

```
<div class="authors">Authored by Jim Smith & Julie Smith</div>
```

I am iterating through the object like this:

```
$.each( obj, function(k,v) {    
  $('.authors').append('<span>' + v.name + '</span>');
});
```

This outputs

```
<div class="authors">Authored by Jim SmithJulie Smith</div>
```

Ideally, a solution will also take into account 1, 2, and 2+ authors such that if there are more than 2 authors, only the last author will have the `&amp;` prefix the value.

For example: if there are three authors: `Jim Smith, Julie Smith, & John Smith`

Notice the usage of the oxford comma.

Should I wrap it in an `if` statement? How best to iterate through an $.each loop while keeping track of the length of the return and which iteration is active?

Comment: What about this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp it can help you ?it is a join function for an array

Comment: that's very promising and succinct, I'll see if it fits the solutions. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use `map()` to build an array of the names from your initial object array. Then you can apply the logic from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41035407/519413) to join the values together in the manner you require for displaying in the UI. Try this:

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "Jim Smith",
  "role": "Author"
}, {
  "name": "Julie Smith",
  "role": "Author"
}, {
  "name": "Foo Smith",
  "role": "Author"
}];

var names = arr.map(function(o) { return o.name; }).join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and');
$('.authors span').text(names);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="authors">Authored by <span></span></div>
```