# separate react native array of strings by comma and enter & before last item?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have an array of names string in react native:

```
const names = ['jay','jake','paul']
```

i want to render them in react native like:

"jay, jake & paul"

i found this [js solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251822/array-to-comma-separated-string-and-for-last-tag-use-the-and-instead-of-comma) and tried something like this but it don't work:

```
names.map((t) => <Text style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>{t}</Text>);

    return names.slice(0, -1).join(<Text>{', '}</Text>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn an array into a string like you want with JavaScript, this should do the trick:

```
const str = `${names.slice(0,-1).join(', ')} & ${names[names.length - 1]}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it :

```
names.slice(0, names.length-1).join(", ") + ' & ' + names[names.length-1]
```